# Nodejs fetch - increase response buffer size for fetch 2.x.x

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch-api

I'm currently implementing sending API request using nodejs-fetch and ran into a problem - as by documentation, max buffer size of fetch is 16kB, while the response i'm trying to get is 53 kB. It results in .fetch() function stuck and never finish. As it's 2.x.x version, and i cant upgrade it, i cant use highWaterMark option for fetch() function. I tried to do as [documetation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/README.md#custom-highwatermark) says "The recommended way to fix this problem is to resolve cloned response in parallel", but either i'm doing it wrong or something else is not quite right.
I'm doing everything according to the doc above, so it's like

```
const response = await fetch('https://example.com');
const r1 = response.clone();

const results = await Promise.all([response.json(), r1.text()]);
```

It still stuck, and i dont even understand how should it help.
How can i solve it to be able to receive a response size of 50+ kB?

Node version 14.12.0, so it's nodejs-fetch package

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using the actual Fetch API, which landed in Node 18, or the `node-fetch` package, which is a completely different thing? Because if you're using the `node-fetch` package: that package is no longer necessary, `fetch` is just a globally available function in modern Node.

Comment: I'm using node-fetch and Node version is 14.12, so i have to use it as a package. Edited the post, thanks

Comment: Node 14 is [no longer supported](https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/), though. So that's something you'll want to have a look at.

Answer (score -1):

Consuming the same stream in two places is complex and prone to error, best to avoid it:

```
const response = await fetch('https://example.com');
const text = await response.text()
const json = JSON.parse(text)
```

Answer (score -2):

So. After the hint i got in the comments, i decided to upgrade to Node v18 to avoid using node-fetch package, and it worked for me from the start

Comment: This is not an answer. Please give the ["how to write a good answer"](/help/how-to-answer) policy article a read-through, and then edit this. If anything, this is a reason to delete the original post, since the solution was to just update to the most recent LTS version of the language in question and use its built-in fetch API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).